# Magento 2 get order item actual price

Tags: magento2, price, order-items

In Magento 2, how can I get order item actual price? 
I tried using below way but it returns 0, although the code is working with Magento 1.9

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class SendOrderTxn implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $orgamount = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
            /* here $orgamount is 0 */
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of how you are loading $order?

Comment: Please, check my updated code.

Comment: You need to use $item->getPrice() method to get actual price.

Comment: I got it by using $item->getOriginalPrice() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
<?php
$orderid = 2;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);

//Loop through each item and fetch data
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
{
   //fetch whole item information
   print_r($item->getData());

   //Or fetch specific item information
   echo $item->getId();
   echo $item->getProductType();
   echo $item->getQtyOrdered();
   echo $item->getPrice(); 

}
?>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This does not work on giftcard product.